# How to kill a Thread with Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, multithreading, kill

I have a call to a third-party C++ library which I have put into its own thread (currently using NSThread). I would like to give the user the ability to stop the execution of that thread. (I am well aware of all the problems this might cause, but I still wish to do so.)

According to [Apple's Thread Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html), there are possibilities in Cocoa to do so. Is this true for the iPhone, too, or do I have to rely on Posix threads to accomplish my goal?

Cheers

MrMage

Comment: If you think you want to stop a thread directly and externally without some kind of synchronization primitive to stop it at a known point then, no, you don't understand the problems it might cause.  One of those problems is very likely a crash or corrupted memory.  Unavoidably so.

Comment: Even when the thread I would like to kill (the worker thread) doesn't use any of the main thread's objects and vice versa?

I have been told by the developer of said library that he happily uses such thread cancellation to stop his worker threads, and that he is not experiencing major problems doing so.

Comment: If his library uses any system library calls in any way, then force killing the thread will lead to undefined behavior.  That includes malloc(), even.  Even if it appears to work now, whether it continues to work across software updates and architecture changes is an entirely different issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to stop your thread executing is to ask it nicely to stop executing. Then, in your thread, you listen for such requests and obey them at an appropriate time.

As the very page you linked to says:

> Although Cocoa, POSIX, and Multiprocessing Services offer routines for killing threads directly, the use of such routines is strongly discouraged. Killing a thread prevents that thread from cleaning up after itself. Memory allocated by the thread could potentially be leaked and any other resources currently in use by the thread might not be cleaned up properly, creating potential problems later.
>
> If you anticipate the need to terminate a thread in the middle of an operation, you should design your threads from the outset to respond to a cancel or exit message. For long-running operations, this might mean stopping work periodically and checking to see if such a message arrived. If a message does come in asking the thread to exit, the thread would then have the opportunity to perform any needed cleanup and exit gracefully; otherwise, it could simply go back to work and process the next chunk of data.