# How to Kill/Stop a background thread?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So I have a method that performs a loop and because of the way my program works i'm calling this method using,

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:arg];
```

And the method itself,

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)arg {
    //...

    for (//Loop Conditions) {
        if (stopMorse) {
            break;
        }
        //Do stuff
    }

    //...
}
```

Now I would like to allow the user to stop this loop from running, so is there a way of killing/stopping the thread.

I've tried adding a BOOL but the problem is that it doesn't seem to get updated because it's on a separate thread. What is the best way to stop this loop from running?

Comment: Tell us where `BOOL stopMorse` is declared (global, class instance, etc.) and show us the code where you change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't forcibly kill/stop the thread for reasons outlined in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351976/how-to-kill-a-thread-with-objective-c/1352023#1352023), and [this answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926879/objective-c-how-to-kill-a-thread-while-in-another-thread-in-objective-c/1926920#1926920).

It should be possible to check a boolean as you are doing, and there shouldn't be a problem with another thread setting the value of the boolean. Can you post the code that is attempting to set the boolean?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to figure it out. Like you said it is possible to check a boolean when another thread sets it. It was just a simple mistake in my code.