# how to cancel the background running thread in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xcode

i wrote like:
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundImageLoading) withObject:nil];
to load image background but know i need to stop this when i refresh the view but i don't have any idea how to do

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(stopImageLoading) withObject:nil]; ?

Comment: in stopimageloading what the code do i need to write to stopn that?

Answer (score 1):

See [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperationQueue).

Its also to do the process concurrently as like background thread. Here in NSOperation you have **cancel** method available to stop the operation.

Answer (score 0):

The threads should not be forced to kill. look out the reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149656/how-to-kill-stop-a-background-thread). It may help you to find the solution.